# Keycloak User role and Admin Role as part of a Group

Tags: security, authentication, keycloak, quarkus, keycloak-rest-api

I have scenario where lets say there are groups Group 1 and Group 2. There are 2 roles, admin and user.
Admin role- it can create users
User role- basically get authenticated to say it belongs to a particular group

Lets say there is a person X part of Group 1 and has role as Admin. This person can only create new users within Group 1 and can not create a user in Group 2. Another person Y is a user of Group 1 when authentication happens it is allowed access to Group 1 stuff but can not see anything for Group 2.

Is this some how possible through Keycloak?
I have tried to implement policies but failed at it. The admin role person is able to create a user in Group 2, it should throw an error which it is not. I am using @RolesAllowed("admin") which give it the access to the endpoint but I was hoping keycloak will fail while trying to create the user
Anyone has any idea on how to implement something like this? Groups having users where the user can be admin/user. Admins/Users have access to only the group they part of. Admins can create more users in that particular group but not any other.